# Spring JPA hibernate postgresql partion and timestamp without timezone

Tags: java, spring, postgresql, hibernate, jpa

After searching a lot, I have a trouble to save timestamp data in PostgreSQL base using Spring JPA Hibernate.

Here my main table in PostgreSQL, it's a partitionning table :

```
CREATE TABLE public.archive_traffic_measure
(
  measure_point_id integer NOT NULL,
  measure_agregation_id integer NOT NULL,
  measure_datetime timestamp without time zone NOT NULL,
  measure_type_id integer NOT NULL,
  any_flow integer,
  f_any_flow smallint,
  hgv_flow integer,
  f_hgv_flow smallint,
  occupation_rate smallint,
  f_occupation_rate smallint,
  average_speed smallint,
  f_average_speed smallint,
  CONSTRAINT pk_archive_traffic_measure PRIMARY KEY (measure_point_id, measure_agregation_id, measure_datetime, measure_type_id)
)
```

Here my main entity with spring JPA hibernate with @SQLInsert to suppress the check and don't have the problem with hibernate that no row is insert (because the row is insert in a child table) :

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "archive_traffic_measure")
@SQLInsert(sql = "INSERT INTO archive_traffic_measure (measure_point_id," +
        "measure_agregation_id," +
        "measure_datetime," +
        "measure_type_id," +
        "any_flow," +
        "f_any_flow," +
        "hgv_flow," +
        "f_hgv_flow," +
        "occupation_rate," +
        "f_occupation_rate," +
        "average_speed," +
        "f_average_speed) VALUES (?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?)", check = ResultCheckStyle.NONE)
public class ArchiveTrafficMeasure implements Serializable {

    @EmbeddedId
    private ArchiveTrafficMeasureId id;

    @Column(name = "any_flow")
    private Integer anyFlow;

    @Column(name = "f_any_flow")
    private Integer F_AnyFlow;

    @Column(name = "hgv_flow")
    private Integer hgvFlow;

    @Column(name = "f_hgv_flow")
    private Integer F_hgvFlow;

    @Column(name = "occupation_rate")
    private Integer occupationRate;

    @Column(name = "f_occupation_rate")
    private Integer F_occupationRate;

    @Column(name = "average_speed")
    private Integer averageSpeed;

    @Column(name = "f_average_speed")
    private Integer F_averageSpeed;
}
```

And my id's entity with Spring JPA hibernate :

```
@Embeddable
@Table(name = "archive_traffic_measure")
public class ArchiveTrafficMeasureId implements Serializable {

    @Column(name = "measure_point_id")
    private int measurePointId;

    @Column(name = "measure_agregation_id")
    private int measureAgregationId;

    @Column(name = "measure_datetime", columnDefinition = "timestamp without time zone")
    @Temporal(TemporalType.TIMESTAMP)
    private Date measureDateTime;

    @Column(name = "measure_type_id")
    private int measureType;
}
```

When I try to insert new data I have this error :

```
ERROR: column "measure_datetime" is of type timestamp without time zone but 
expression is of type integer
```

The problem is the request be like :
INSERT INTO archive_traffic_measure VALUES (1,2,2018-04-18 17:00:00+01,1,40,null,null,null,null,null,null,null)

So the quote arount the timestamp is missing...

I have try to put the quote in the @SQLInsert "(?,?,'?',?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?)" but with that, I have the error :
The column's index is out of bound : 12, number of column : 11.

I have also try "(?,?,''?'',?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?)" with double quote 
Or "(?,?,?::timestamp,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?)" but nothing is working for far.

Can someone help me ? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

First, add `nullable = false` for 'measure_datetime' column definition also remove composite key from @SQLInsert:

```
@SQLInsert(sql = "INSERT INTO archive_traffic_measure ("any_flow," +
        "f_any_flow," +
        "hgv_flow," +
        "f_hgv_flow," +
        "occupation_rate," +
        "f_occupation_rate," +
        "average_speed," +
        "f_average_speed) VALUES (?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?)", check = ResultCheckStyle.NONE)
```

Then, when you persist ArchiveTrafficMeasure, you should set PK as ArchiveTrafficMeasureId and persist it.